# How to remove white background with some shadow in grabcut?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

I am using grabcut to remove the white background from the images. Some part of the background at the edges remain. Can you please help me to remove the shadow part as well ?

Input image

[image: Input image]

Output image

[image: output image]

Tried grabcut, contour, normal thresholding but shadow remains

```
img_ray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(img_ray, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = contours[4]
cv.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 3)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
bgdmodel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdmodel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
rect = (50, 0, width, height)
cv.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdmodel, fgdmodel, 10, cv.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
img = img * mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
img[np.where((img == [230, 230, 230]).all(axis=2))] = [0, 0, 0]
cv.bitwise_not(img)
```

it should remove complete background

Answer (score 3):

This answer explains how to use Grabcut and a mask to extract the foreground. There are two steps in this answer. The first step is creating a mask that labels the pixels as sure foreground, sure background, or unknown. The second step is applying the Grabcut algorithm.

The mask is created using the `Canny` edge filter and two [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html).

```
edges = cv.Canny(img, 80,150)
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
closing = cv.morphologyEx(edges, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)
erosion = cv.morphologyEx(closing, cv.MORPH_ERODE, kernel, iterations=1)

# When using Grabcut the mask image should be:
#    0 - sure background
#    1 - sure foreground
#    2 - unknown

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
mask[:] = 2
mask[erosion == 255] = 1
```

This mask will give the Grabcut algorithm hints about what is the sure foreground and what is the sure background. Next, apply Grabcut with the mask:

```
bgdmodel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdmodel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)

out_mask = mask.copy()
out_mask, _, _ = cv.grabCut(img,out_mask,None,bgdmodel,fgdmodel,1,cv.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
out_mask = np.where((out_mask==2)|(out_mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
out_img = img*out_mask[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

The `mask` is shown as `mask*123` so that sure forground is gray, sure background is black, and unknown is white:
[image: output]

Comment: it works for the above image, but not for other jewelry images like below. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1weGPeAYGxeGOeSX4EPZ4MJ1HSD3LphJE/view?usp=sharing                
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gMk5nOdYUyH21sa6pxI_aliaOH-sFlK5/view?usp=sharing 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XkB4RCPB541bSkXI21rk8FS01HYgfwC2/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                                  Any way to improve the accuracy?

Comment: @VedantBHegde I need the source images for more testing.

Comment: Here are the source images                
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1umi5CkeUF-P5cGVYGmiMEWAp3j3HIDaT/view?usp=sharing                                 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MQqw2es1ClFMxY5o3A-8Bnx9kO4adhT4/view?usp=sharing                                                   
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PFEo-hFOYOUKLUM53EzlbMGdSxZcJSkI/view?usp=sharing                                                            https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yOkHOMVtG5-EmYTN-XkXQeDLKG2YTe4H/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://www.remove.bg/ This website works well. Not sure how they did it.

Comment: did you get any solution @Stephen

Comment: @VedantBHegde Do you want an alpha-matte for these images? I think that you will have better results re-taking these pictures with better lit background. If you can't take pictures, you could render these items.